# Best way to show content from my Rails app on other websites -- iFrame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I built a Rails app that companies use in retail stores.  The main page is a series of dynamic select menus that determine a cellphone model and then show the value of that phone to the user.

[image]

The companies that use our app want to show this page on their website so their customers can check phone values before coming to a store.

My instinct is to build a special public-facing page on my Heroku-hosted Rails app, and have these clients use an iFrame to show the content.  But I also know that iFrames are often not a reliable solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an equivalent. The  element is still valid in HTML5. Depending on what exact interaction you need there might be different APIs. For example there's the postMessage method which allows you to achieve cross domain javascript interaction. But if you want to display cross domain HTML contents (styled with CSS and made interactive with javascript) iframe stays as a good way to do.